# Server gives exception and fails to start

Tags: c#, tcp, websocket

lately I started to learn about Tcp/ip sockets in c#, so I watched a tutorials and read online about it. I followed tutorial and I made client-server app that is sending simple text to the server on the same network. I tried to "upgrade" and make client communicate with other client that is on different network thru server. But now server fails to start saying that "The requested address is not valid in its context".

```
First was server running as localhost, but now when I want to clients that are in different networks communicate through server , server needs to run on my ip address so other client in different network could connect.  I did IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("my IP"); and  TcpListener  server = new TcpListener(ip, 10000); I tried using different ports but its still the same. 


This is what exceptions tells me 
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start()

 IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.5"); //Mock IP

            TcpListener  server = new TcpListener(ip, 8080);


            TcpClient client = default(TcpClient); 
            TcpClient client2 = default(TcpClient);

            try
            {
                server.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Server started...");


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server failed to start... {0}",ex.ToString());
                Console.Read();

            }

            while (true)
            {
                client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

               client2 = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[1000]; 

                byte[] receivedBuffer2 =  new byte[1000];

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); 

                NetworkStream stream2 = client2.GetStream();

                stream.Read(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length); 

                stream2.Read(receivedBuffer2, 0, receivedBuffer2.Length);

                StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();     
                foreach (byte b in receivedBuffer) 
                {
                    if (b.Equals(126))         
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message.Append(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());
                    }
                }
                StringBuilder message2 = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (byte g in receivedBuffer2)
                {
                    if (g.Equals(126))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message2.Append(g);
                    }
                }
                //string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);

                Console.WriteLine(message.ToString() + message.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(message2.ToString() +message2.Length);
```

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Line 26 when server is supposed to start.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netframework-4.7.2) is MSDN reference for using `TcpListener` just as a reference. -- Firstly, I would hope that isn't your actual `IP` given in the question, and if it is, I recommend changing it (within the question) for security. Then , I would verify if anything is already running on `port 8080`. Have you tried different ports?

Comment: I tried to change ports but its saying that ip its not valid for some reason but when i start it from local ipv4 address with same port it works.

Comment: It is working only with local ip.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `The requested address is not valid in its context` means that the IP address you have used is not tied to any network interface on your machine.
You typically don't want to hard-code a specific IP address that you listen to (e.g. if your machine get's it IP through DHCP it could change).

Better way is to use [IPAddress.Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.any) to listen on all IP addresses (i.e. network interface) available on the machine.